# How to import custom module with twistd

Tags: python, twisted

I have a python file that I want to run using twistd. Inside the file I have:

```
from parser import Parser
```

I also have a `parser.py` file with a `Parser` class inside.

Everything works fine when I invoke the script using:

```
python myscript.py
```

But then I call it using:

```
twistd -y myscript.py
```

it gives me this error:

```
from parser import Parser
exceptions.ImportError: cannot import name Parser
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source files for import as modules need to be discoverable on the Python import path.  `python` adds the directory containing the script path to the import path.  Since you have `parser.py` in the same directory as `myscript.py`, this makes `parser` importable.  `twistd` (starting with some version in 2016, I think) does *not* do this (adding the path was considered a security issue similar to the one created by having `.` in the `PATH` environment variable).

You have a few options.

Best option: Create a setup.py for your project.  Create a virtualenv.  Install your project into it with `pip install -e ...`.

Mediocre option: Add the directory containing your source files to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.